# My function returns an object but I am unable to access the object's properties through the return value.

Tags: c++, object

```
Person Search(std::string SearchedName, std::vector<Person>People)  
{
    for (int i = 0; i<People.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<People.size(); j++)
        {
            if (People[j].Name == SearchedName)
            {
                return People[j];
            }
        }
    }
}


void Distribute(Person &InputPerson, std::vector<Person> &People)
{
    int x, y;
    fin >> x >> y;
    InputPerson.MoneyOut = x;
    InputPerson.Recipients = y;
    std::cout << x << "\t" << y << std::endl;
    if (x)
    {
        int MoneyEach = x / y;
        for (int i = 0; i<y; i++)
        {
            std::string Input;
            fin >> Input;
            Search(Input, People).MoneyIn += MoneyEach; //The command line //gives the error here as "using temporary as lvalue.
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a Person class, and a vector containing several Person objects. I receive a string and search the vector for the object with that string as a name, using the Search function, returning said object, but then I get a compiler error when I try and use a property of that returned object. Could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Returning copies is perfectly well defined.  Returning a reference or const reference here (without any other changes) will be problematic because the `vector<Person> people` is itself taken by copy.

Comment: Btw, what do you think your function returns when it **fails** to find a match? And is that `i` loop *really* needed?

Comment: I've no idea what it returns when it fails to find a match, but in the problem I'm working on, it should always find a match, so is there much point in worrying about that? Concerning the i loop, how else would you iterate through the vector to find the necessary object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns `Person` by value (thus making a copy), and you are trying to modify the returned value. This is prohibited by the language (you can't convert rvalue to lvalue), and that's probably not what you want.

What you probably want is to return the object by reference. Also it's `People` parameter should also be a reference, otherwise you'll return a dangling reference:

```
Person& Search(std::string SearchedName, std::vector<Person>& People)
```

But you have to decide what to return if the function finds nothing (BTW now your function returns nothing, which is undefined behavior).

One option is to throw an exception in that case, another one is to return a pointer and check it in the calling function:

```
Person* Search(std::string SearchedName, std::vector<Person>& People)
// ... 
// return &People[j]; 
// at the end return nullptr;
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the _reason_ it's prohibited by the language is precisely because it's basically never what you want. This problem is essentially a compiler warning on crack.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'd been having a lot of trouble there. It's been my first time using objects so I'd never returned by reference, only passed arguments by reference, so that was something of uncharted territory for me. A follow up question though: when you return a non-object value, like an int or a string, can you return it by reference, and if so, is there any point/difference in doing so? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You return a copy of person, so don't modify the element in vector.

Moreover, if `Search` fails, you have undefined behaviour (no return).

The code should look like:

```
Person& Search(const std::string& searchedName, std::vector<Person>& people)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(),
                           [&](const Person& p) {
                               return p..Name == SearchedName;
                           });
    if (it == people.end()) { // Not found
        throw std::runtime_error("person not found");
    }
    return *it;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with object lifetimes.

The function:

```
Person Search(std::string SearchedName, std::vector<Person>People)
```

Returns a copy of a `Person` object.  This copy is "temporary", it will only exist until the statement is completed.

You can create a copy of it:

```
Person p = Search("Chad", people);
```

`p` has now been copied from whatever was returned from `Search`.

The compiler is being helpful in warning you that you can't use the temporary object in the manner that you are trying to.

All this aside, looking at your code what you appear to be trying to do is distribute some money to a person by name.  Since it's plausible that you want this to persist, you can make some minor changes to your code and make it work.

```
Person& Search(std::string SearchedName, std::vector<Person>& People)
```

By returning a reference here **and** taking the input `vector` by reference you now have the ability to do what (*I think*) you are trying to do.

If you don't understand references yet, get yourself a good book.

Comment: _"The compiler is being helpful in warning you"_ I don't dislike the way you phrased this: it's precisely the reason for the language rule. But it _is_ a language rule and, as such, technically it's really the language itself that's being helpful (the compiler is just abiding by that law) and it's much more than a mere warning. Just saying as the OP may benefit from hearing _both_ interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

An lvalue is a value that can be put on the left side of the equal. When you return the `People` object from your search function, you are returning a copy of it as a temporary value (this is how C++ works): assigning to temporary values is not possible, you need to assign it first to a variable and then modify the properties.

I believe your purpose is modifying the return object itself, therefore you must return a reference as suggested in the comments.